# Javascript Arguments object not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arguments

When I set `arugments[0] = chewie;  arguments[1] = luke` it prints:

**Chewbacca**

**Chewbacca**

**Han Solo**

**Chewbacca**

And what I expected was the following:

**Chewbacca**

**Luke Skywalker**

**Han Solo**

**Chewbacca**

```js
function starWars(luke, darth, han, chewie) {

   arguments[0] = chewie;
   arguments[1] = luke;

   document.write(arguments[0] + "<br>");
   document.write(arguments[1] + "<br>");
   document.write(arguments[2] + "<br>");
   document.write(arguments[3] + "<br>");
 
} 

starWars("Luke Skywalker", "Darth Vader", "Han Solo", "Chewbacca");
```

Can anyone explain me in details why it is not working as I expected?

Comment: You should **not** be assigning values to `arguments` manually. In almost every case, it's no longer necessary to use the `arguments` object in ES2015 or later

Comment: Because `arguments[0]` and `luke` are the exact same thing. Not two references to the same value, but basically both are **kind of the same variable**. If you change `arguments[0]`, `luke` will also be changed; and vice versa. So much for the knowledge; no reason to explit or even use this. Listen to @naomik, avoid the `arguments` object as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In loose mode, the entries in `arguments` are **linked** to the named parameters. So by setting `arguments[0]`, you're setting `luke.` Literally, the lines `arguments[0] = chewie;` and `luke = chewie;` are interchangeable. So later when you use `arguments[1]` from `luke`, you're using the updated value (`chewie`).

Strict mode removes this magic link:

```js
"use strict";
function starWars(luke, darth, han, chewie) {

   arguments[0] = chewie;
   arguments[1] = luke;

   console.log(arguments[0]);
   console.log(arguments[1]);
   console.log(arguments[2]);
   console.log(arguments[3]);
 
} 

starWars("Luke Skywalker", "Darth Vader", "Han Solo", "Chewbacca");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-assigning the `luke` variable with `chewie` since `argument[0]` is a **reference** to `luke`.

So after `arguments[0] = chewie`, what happens is `luke = chewie`.

A workaround could be :

```
var tempLuke = argument[0];
arguments[0] = chewie;
arguments[1] = tempLuke;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change `arguments` object, you also change the argument variables of the function, because it holds references to the variables.

To summarize

1) `arguments[0] = chewie;`

Here, you also set variable `luke` to chewie ('chewbacca')

2) arguments[1] = luke;

Here, luke is already became 'chewbacca' in the first step. So, you are making argument `dart` also 'chewbacca'.